# Thread daemon не работает

Tags: java, многопоточность, daemon

Поток класса **MyThread** считает определенным образом **sum** , поток **Demon** выводит **sum** раз в 5ms. Ну, это в теории. Но у меня почему то после первого подходящего по условию числа (**6**) оно выводится и оба потока останавливаются. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем ошибка?

```
public class Task_1 extends Thread {
    private static int sum = 0;

    static int getSum() {
        return sum;
    }

    static void setSum(int sum) {
        Task_1.sum = sum;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainThread first = new MainThread();
        Demon demon = new Demon();

        demon.setDaemon(true);
        first.start();
        demon.start();
    }
}

class Demon extends Task_1 {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(getSum());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5);
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class MainThread extends Task_1 {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
            if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 2 == 0) {
                setSum(getSum() + i);
            }
            if (i == 10) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                    ie.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы же цикл не сделали.

```java
class Demon extends Task_1 {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            System.out.println(getSum());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5);
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                ie.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Да, все работает, только я не совсем понимаю.
Можете объяснить что именно этот while проверяет? (Обычно в процессе учебы сталкиваюсь с привязкой условия к некому конкретному полю (прим. while i < 10 и т.п.)

Comment: И еще компилятор warning'ами ругается на такой цикл

Comment: @hankuk он ничего не проверяет, в него передаётся условие `true`, то есть истина, другими словами, это вечный цикл. Неважно, что компилятор ругается, в `daemon` потоках как раз и нужно делать вечные циклы.

Comment: Все, разобрался, спасибо большое!)

Comment: @hankuk компилятор, кстати, не ругается, а предупреждает, что цикл бесконечный.